# Complex mysql query - grouping and ordering by date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a news list, with three categories. Let's say category1, category2, category3. Each article has a publish date. Now is it possible to get the list as follows:

```
most recent article in category1
most recent article in category2
most recent article in category3
second most recent article in category1
second most recent article in category2
second most recent article in category3
```

And if both category1 and category3 have one article left while category2 has run out of articles, the above list will be followed by:

```
third most recent article in category1
third most recent article in category3
```

I don't know if this is possible in mysql query. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If your category Number is limited you can loop it and in every loop, concat the sqls with UNION; the this sql:
`"SELECT * FROM news WHERE 1 GROUP BY ".$category." ORDER BY publish_date DESC LIMIT ".$categoryCount." UNION ALL"`

Note: Don't forget the substr the last "UNION ALL" string

Comment: no, the category name are mocked here, could be any string.

Answer (score 0):

I see questions like this so often, especially when it comes to web-based app content.  I want the most recent X per Whatever.  In this case, you want the most recent 3 articles.  Instead of trying to structure queries that will be a pain to work with, I would suggest denormalizing the data for the news category table..

Add 3 columns for the most recent 3 articles.  Then, add a trigger to the articles table.  When an article is added to the table, do an update to the category table with it as the newest position, and shift the other two down so it is always rolling...  Not positive on the trigger syntax, but something like the following for the update...

```
update Category 
   set ThirdArticleID = SecondArticleID, 
       SecondArticleID = FirstArticleID, 
       FirstArticleID = NewArticleIDJustAdded
   where CategoryID = NewArticleCategoryID
```

Then, you can just do left-join per category and always have the "latest 3" something like

```
select
      c.*,
      A1.ArticleTitle as FirstArticle,
      A2.ArticleTitle as SecondArticle,
      A3.ArticleTitle as ThirdArticle
   from
      Category C
         LEFT JOIN Articles A1
            on C.FirstArticleID = A1.ArticleID
         LEFT JOIN Articles A2
            on C.SecondArticleID = A2.ArticleID
         LEFT JOIN Articles A3
            on C.ThirdArticleID = A3.ArticleID
```

Then you dont have any min(), max(), group by, order by desc, etc to worry about. You may want to pre-prime these category article entries, but after the entries get new articles, it will be self-synchronizing.